# How to rsync over ssh

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have two virgin DigitalOcean Centos 7 VM's. test1 and test2.

/etc/rsyncd.conf on test1:

```
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
[test]
path = /home/xfer
```

This works. From test1: **rsync -av --progress [test1 IP]::test/testFile .**

However, I want to do it over ssh and firewall the rsync port. I have tried so many variations and it seems so simple but I just can't get it to work. This does NOT work:

**rsync -avz -e "ssh -l xfer" --progress xfer@[test1 IP]::test/testFile  .**

rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I was unaware rsync had been updated to do ssh natively. Was still trying to do it the way I did it years ago. This works:

**rsync -va  xfer@[test1 IP]:test/testFile .**

Comment: What about just using a single ":" (the simple way to do ssh): `rsync -av --progress [test1 IP]::test/testFile .` Note that this does not require or use rsyncd, it just opens a remote shell and runs `rsync` in that.

Comment: Well Tim, check this post here for many explanations of why this could be occurring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899080/error-in-rsync-protocol-data-stream-code-12-at-io-c605-receiver-3-0-9. If it's a large file then that may be the case in your instance or perhaps one of the other answers from there that others that ran into this error had, etc. Maybe you can reverse the push pull location and from which server to get the expected result as a quick workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did figure it out and updated my question.